# Python XML parsing w/duplicate tag names

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using python 2.7x with ElementTree.
I'm very new to XML parsing and I am having a little trouble getting the text value of the 2nd tag with the name 'status'.

The XML is structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<result>
 <teststatus>
  <test_id>Read_44</test_id>
  <pass_ios>0</pass_ios>
  <seek_type>Sequential</seek_type>
  <multipath_mode>0</multipath_mode>
  <start_time>Jul 16 11:13:24</start_time>
  <end_time>Jul 16 11:14:52</end_time>
  <test_time>00:01:28</test_time>
  <test_ios>1572864</test_ios>
  <test_bytes>6442450944</test_bytes>
  <test_errors>0</test_errors>
  <test_read_errors>0</test_read_errors>
  <test_write_errors>0</test_write_errors>
  <test_compare_errors>0</test_compare_errors>
  <num_test_luns>1</num_test_luns>
  <luns xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <port>10</port>
  <target>0</target>
  <lun_id>0</lun_id>
  <status>Passed</status>  <-- Current State of the Test
  <ios_done>1572864</ios_done>
  <bytes_done>6442450944</bytes_done>
  <errors>83011124</errors>
  <threads_done>0</threads_done>
  </lun></luns>
 </teststatus>
 <status>0</status>  <------ XML Test Status Request Succeeded
</result>
```

I need to find the 1st Child 'status' tag and confirm it's Text value is = 0 and that is working fine with the following code:

```
root = ET.fromstring(commandResponseXML)
            for child in root:
                print(child.tag, child.text)
                if ( child.text == '0' and child.tag == 'status' ):
                ----Do things here
```

My problem is getting the Text value from the 2nd `<status>` tag below the `<teststatus>`.

I am using 'findall' but the child tag and trying to 'set' the level to the `<teststatus>` but the resulting child value 'status' never seems to be found:

```
for testStatusResponse in root.findall('.//teststatus'):
                for newchild in testStatusResponse:
                    if newchild.tag == "status":
                        testState = testStatusResponse.text
                        s = "---The updated Test State is " + str(testState)
                        print s
                        openOutput.write(s  + "\n")
```

Comment: Ignoring the `<----` comments, your XML input still isn't well-formed. You're either missing a `lun` start tag or need to remove the unneeded `</lun>` end tag. That's going to make a big difference in trying to get the `status` that is a descendant of `teststatus`.

Comment: I think that I see what is happening now.
The iteration is halting on two incomplete tags in the output:
<luns xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<lun id="10 0 0" xlink:href="http://10.10.64.208/goform/XmlApi?op=VlunLunStatus&amp;port=10&amp;target=0&amp;lun=0">

Comment: SOLVED: After pushing the XML to https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html I can see that there was more depth to the response fields than I had previously thought. Moving deeper down the tag structure fixed it for me.